# AWS Spinnaker local install on ec2 issues: You are not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, spinnaker

i did configuration as mentioned in `https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/providers/aws/` and starting spinnaker and keep getting this error in clouddriver.logs

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: You are not authorized to perform this operation. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 403; Error Code: UnauthorizedOperation; Request ID: fb3144e7-7105-44e1-917c-60c6de551d83)
```

My installation environment is AWS ec2 environment and this instance is having role `BaseIAMRole` and have attached `SpinnakerAssumeRolePolicy` and `PowerUserAccess` to it.

I have configuration for the managing account and managed account in my clouddriver.yml Like this:

```
aws:
  enabled: true
  accounts:
  - name: '07xxxx...'
#    requiredGroupMembership: []
    accountId: '07xxxx...'
    regions: []
    assumeRole: role/spinnakerManaged
  - name: '19xxxx...'
  #    requiredGroupMembership: []
    accountId: '19xxxx...'
    regions: []
    assumeRole: role/spinnakerManaged
  primaryAccount: '07xxxx...'
  defaultKeyPairTemplate: '{{name}}-keypair'
  defaultRegions:
  - name: ap-southeast-2
  defaultAssumeRole: role/spinnakerManaged
  defaults:
    iamRole: BaseIAMRole
```

I have admin access to both managing and managed accounts...

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

IT seems you are missing the AWS IAM policies that must be attached and set up so that the managing role and managed role settings take effect. 
Please refer to the documentation at: [Armory AWS IAM set up](https://docs.armory.io/spinnaker-install-admin-guides/add-aws-account-iam/)